# Getting buttons data into different labels

Tags: button, label

I'm new. I've determined I cannot make a label "active" and accept keyboard input, so I am trying text fields instead. Seeking advice as to how to kill off the built in keyboard when the user taps the text field, as I want to use my own keyboard (a series of images).

I can determine the active text field (textfield.editing == yes), but when I will kill of the keyboard it seems it also kills off the ability to enter any data into that text field.

Maybe I need to just "hide" the keyboard? Send it off the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a way to make this happen.  I created some transparent buttons, and laid those over the top of the labels.  When the button gets clicked, it designates the label below it should be the active label.

In a separate method, the users text runs thru a few conditions to determine which label (as designated by the transparent button)  is active, and the text goes into that label.